# Using py2exe to create windows service

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-services, py2exe

I need to run my python app as windows service.
I'm able to do that using commands,
`python fservice.py install`

`python fservice.py start`

Now, i want to create exe for my app using py2exe.
I've followed code from this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770873/python-windows-service-pyinstaller-executables-error-1053)
**setup.py**

```python
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys


if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.argv.append("py2exe")
    sys.argv.append("-q")


class Target:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.__dict__.update(kw)
        # for the versioninfo resources
        self.version = "0.0.1"
        self.company_name = "flotomate"
        self.copyright = "no copyright"
        self.name = "flotomate"

myservice = Target(
     # used for the versioninfo resource
     description = "flotomate",
     # what to build.  For a service, the module name (not the
     # filename) must be specified!
     modules = ["fservice"]
     )

setup(
     service = [myservice]
    )
```

**fservice.py**

```python
import sys

import servicemanager
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import win32api
from pagent import app


class fservice(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'flotomate' #here is now the name you would input as an arg for instart
    _svc_display_name_ = 'flotomate' #arg for instart
    _svc_description_ = 'flotomate'# arg from instart

    def __init__(self, *args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, *args)
        self.log('init')
        self.stop_event = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)


        #logs into the system event log
    def log(self, msg):
        import servicemanager
        servicemanager.LogInfoMsg(str(msg))

    def sleep(self, minute):
            win32api.Sleep((minute*1000), True)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        try:
            self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
            self.log('start')
            self.start()
            self.log('wait')
            win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.stop_event, win32event.INFINITE)
            self.log('done')
        except Exception:
            self.SvcStop()

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        self.stop()
        win32event.SetEvent(self.stop_event)
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)

    def start(self):
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=4999)

    # to be overridden
    def stop(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(fservice)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(fservice)
```

I'm creating exe using command,
`python setup.py py2exe`
but, when i try to install the service using 
`fservice.exe --install`
I get this error

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boot_service.py", line 37, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Initialize
```

[boot_service.py of py2exe](https://github.com/goatpig/py2exe/blob/35ad88369fff3b171f131ae64f98aafb06626774/py2exe/boot_service.py)

I'm using Python 2.7.6 and py2exe-0.6.9

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I don't know whether you found the solution yet

In my case, the reason would be that *servicemanager* is not included in the compiled package. It seems the installed *servicemanager* library in python issues conflict.

To solve this problem, I uninstall *servicemanager* if it is unused or manually copy *servicemanager.pyd* to folder *dist* and servicemager.pyc to *dist\library.zip*. If there is a folder named *servicemanager* in *dist\library.zip*, just delete it.

If you already had a better solution, please share it ^^