# Multiprocessing in pywin32 service

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pywin32

My process does not seem to be created when the .exe runs as a service.
The service is created with pywin32 and the process should only log something and sleep. When the .exe is run normally, the process does work but when it is built and installed as a service it does not work.
The .exe is build with pyinstaller.
This is how I create a service:

```
class TestService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
_svc_name_ = "Test_SERVICE"
_svc_display_name_ = "Test_SERVICE"
_svc_description_ = "Any Description"

def SvcStop(self):
    """
    Stops the server and the service
    """
    # report method also sets the status of the service
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)
    servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                          servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STOPPED,
                          (TestService._svc_name_, 'SVC Stop'))

def SvcDoRun(self):
    """
    Call the main method to start the service
    """
    servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                          servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTING,
                          (TestService._svc_name_, 'SVC RUN'))
    try:
        self.main()
    except Exception:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STOPPED,
                              (TestService._svc_name_,
                               traceback.format_exc()))
    else:
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STOPPED,
                              (TestService._svc_name_, ''))

def main(self):
    """
    Starts the service
    """
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    execute()

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
# If there is no cmdline argument, app was started by windows service manager.
# assuming here we are running 'frozen'
    if not hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
        print(
        "Can't start, need a frozen setup (executable created with pyinstaller) when started without arguments!\n")
        win32serviceutil.usage()
        sys.exit(1)
    try:
        # start service according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770873/python-windows-service-pyinstaller-executables-error-1053,at the bottom
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(TestService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()

    except Exception as error:
        # log any exception that occurs during startup
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE,
                          servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STOPPED,
                          (TestService._svc_name_, error))
    raise
else:
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(TestService)
```

And this is the execute method with the new process:

```
def execute():
    proc = Process(target=log_and_sleep)
    proc.start()
    proc.join()

def log_and_sleep():
    servicemanager.LogInfoMsg('Test')
    time.sleep(10)
```

The log message from the new process will not appear in the windows event logs as soon as it runs as a service.

Does anyone no how the new process can be created correctly to run inside the service?

Comment: could you fix the formatting in your code please. I find code fences `\`\`\` my code \`\`\`` work better than the indent method.

Comment: Before I dive in to looking up your actual question.. I have successfully used task scheduler many times to automate python scripts without issue, and I never compile to exe.. I simply call the python executable with my script file.

Comment: The described problem is specificly for pywin32 service. To run the python code automatically with task sheduling is not what i am looking for

Comment: seems to me like whatever organizes `SvcDoRun` to be called is not the same between `if len(sys.argv) == 1:` and `else`. I'm also concerned at not seeing `if __name__ == "__main__":`, but you do say it works outside of a service call...